# How to easly integrate a Silverlight application into Dynamics CRM in regards of the look and feel / UI style

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm

How to apply the crm look and feel to a silverlight application? How can I apply those CSS Styles to the silverlight UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Silverlight has no support for css. I suppose it is possible to write some sort of css parser that translates the values you need into XAML Styles that Silverlight can use. But that would be a *lot* of work, unless you are 100% certain that your css is very simple and only uses a few known style attributes, which I think will not be the case for that CRM system. Since you are asking for a way to "easily integrate...", the answer has to be no. There is no easy way.

Comment: MS should provide a XAML crm Style, any hints about that?

Comment: I haven't heard anything about that and I doubt whether it will happen. Unless of course they start including a lot of Silverlight-based functionality in the CRM itself. Then they might decide to support XAML styles. But really, I am only guessing... Also, you should know that css and XAML styles do not work in the same way. XAML styles are something you include when you compile your app. After that they can't really be changed, at least not without a lot of hard work. So if Microsoft DID want to support Silverlight integration they would have to come up with some kind of clever framework.